# @page :first { margin: ... } in Chrome bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

Referring to the full fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/XT92a/

```
@page {
    margin: 1in;
}

@page :first {
    margin: 2in 1in 3in 3in;
}
```

I expect the above rule to make the first printed page have certain margins and all other pages have 1 inch margins.

Instead, I get the following in Chrome's print preview (accurate to the printed output).  The margins *are* different on the non-first pages, but they are not correct.  Commenting out the `:first margin` rule allows the non-first pages to print with the correct layout, but of course, the first page is also affected.

[Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@page) seems to me to claim that Chrome supports this properly.  And clearly Chrome reacts, but not correctly.  I'd reference Chrome documentation if I could, but Google sucks at documentation!  (Is there a google equivalent of the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@page)?  I can't find it.)

It's strange to me that I can't find mention of this problem elsewhere, if Chrome should have supported this since version 2.0 and that print layouts are such a huge PITA.

Am I doing it wrong?  Is there a robust workaround?  I've tried `@page:first` (no space), setting margin values independently trbl style and individually, and swapped the order of the rules in the style declarations.  No effect.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You stated:

> Mozilla's documentation seems to me to claim that Chrome supports this
>   properly.

True, but [the `:first` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first) shows unknown support from Chrome ("Unknown support. Please update this."

[Also, there are many print preview issues with Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=print%20preview&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&x=mstone&y=releaseblock&cells=tiles) and I stumbled across some that sounded similar to this problem [such as this one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107912&q=print%20preview%20margin&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary). Nevertheless, I could find no work arounds. Just so you are aware in your own testing I tried:

- negative margins
- padding rather than margins
- large borders to simulate margins
- [forced page breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/page-break-after) (possible hack solution)
- explicit `width` and `height`
- `!important`

I performed a lot of testing and **Chrome appears to ignore or improperly implement the CSS rules when generating the preview PDF file**. Personally, from my testing results, I think this is a bug.

**Update**

- Firefox v17.0.1 - Does not apply `@page` rules at all.
- Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m - incorrectly applies the `:first` pseudo class on all pages.
- IE 9.0.8112.16421 - performs the same misapplication of rules as Chrome

My findings coincide with the [browser compatibility chart on the `:first` pseudo class page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first). That is, an unknown compatibility for Chrome and a "not supported" compatibility for Firefox. I was unable to test IE8, but my test with IE9 does not support the chart's claim. Even Microsoft's examples fail to render correctly ([CSS How-to: Optimize Pages for Printing Using CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

[image: :first Browser compatibility]

After more testing, I can only conclude that `@page` hasn't been completely integrated into most browsers. The specifications are present ([there are new specs. for CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)) but based on our tests, the lack of tested examples in articles, and the bug reports it looks like you won't be able to successfully use the more flexible specs of the `@page` styling.

Comment: Interesting find about the `:first`-specific page.  I didn't see that was a link.  But see that the `:first`-specific page shows support in IE 8.0, but that isn't true.  In fact, it seems to act just like Chrome which is interesting.  Perhaps I'm using it wrong?

Comment: I don't think so. I mention in my answer that IE9 has the same problems. I'm sure IE8 is no different.

Comment: Using `transform:scale` also doesn't work for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked in my case and made all margins similar across all pages. Before, first page used to give bigger margin.
Instead of using margin-top:20px use padding-top:20px in the block which is going first in page div. This may be

Works:

```
header {
    margin:0px 80px 20px 80px;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

Not working (gives bigger top margin on first page):

```
header {
    margin:50px 80px 20px 80px;
}
```