# Changing print margins using CSS @page :first causes other pages to cut off text

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, print-css

I am trying to format a webpage for printing. The first page is a cover page with full bleed background. The rest of the pages have a margin.

```
@page {
   margin: 2cm;
}
@page :first {
   margin: 0;
}
.cover {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   page-break-after: always;
}

<div class="cover"></div>
<p>HUGE BLOCK OF BODY TEXT...</p>
```

The first page looks perfect with no margin, but all the remaining pages with the margin have the text cut off.

[First page with 0 margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lepUW.png)

[Inner page with 2cm margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUG5t.png)

The problem seems to be the first page. When I comment out the the margin: 0 for the first page, all the remaining pages look correct.

[First page with 2cm margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSys2.png)

[Inner page with 2cm margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKJVy.png)

Is there a correct way to change margins using @page :first that doesn't affect the remaining pages?

Answer (score 1):

Took awhile searching but appears that it has come up before as a possible bug with Chrome.

See this other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008461/704765

The padding solution could work, if you had a container for the content and applied a 2cm padding, however at page-breaks it doesn't apply padding on top or bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and found some workaround to fix this. In my approach I create wrappers for pages which have at least 1 page height and force every wrapper after first one to have specific `max-width`. I guess that chrome have bad implementation of calculating `width: 100%` and base it on the first page margin every time.

CSS:

```
@page {
  margin: 2cm;
}
@page:first {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
section.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  page-break-before: always;
}
section.page--cover {
  background-color: blue;
}
section.page:not(:first-child) {
  /* We need to force page content to not be wider than actual page width */
  max-width: calc(100% - 4cm); /* (first page margin) x 2 */
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="page page--cover">
  first cover page in wrapper (@page margin 0)
</section>
<section class="page">
  second page in wrapper (@page margin 2cm)
  content here can be longer then page height, in this solution 
  page break's should be working fine with given 2cm margins.
</section>
```